# Calculating distance between point and circle in PostgreSQL, what units are used for circle radius and distance?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using geometric functions and operators: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-geometry.html

Table 'bank' Containing a geofence the type of which is `circle` with a 0.5 Radius.

```
id       name   geofence  
"ID123";"FAR";"<(-122.31562661719,49.051595254425),0.5>"
"ID456";"NEAR";"<(-83.110566270539,42.102925914015),0.5>"
```

Table 'points' Containing lat_lon as a `point`

```
id    url              lat_lon              device
"455";"www.google.com";"(-83.0163,42.2733)";"48ddb459104986c1860eaa048ad72525ac881651"
```

I am trying to find all the points that are within a geofence.

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  points, bank
WHERE lat_lon <@ bank.geofence;
```

The results I get are close to the point I am checking for, but they are not within the 0.5KM radius when I check them on the map.

For the above two points, if I print out the distance as a column

```
SELECT *, lat_lon <-> bank.geofence
FROM 
  points, bank;
```

Gives me a value of 39.3795 for the FAR point, and a 0 for the NEAR point. I know that both aren't within the geofence, but I am trying to figure out the units used for Radius and for Distance.

So, what unit is the radius field in a circle?
If I want 500m what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all in the same unit (or more accurately, none at all). You could call it meters, inches or something else. What you refer to as `lat_lon` is just a point in a plane right now, as is the circle.

The distance is calculated using basic geometry (the pythagorean theorem):

```
a = 83.0163 - 122.31562661719
b = 42.2733 - 49.051595254425
c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = 39.212992455
```

Comment: And how would I go about finding the actual distance between two points on the surface of the earth?

Comment: In that case I would recommend you to use Postgis (http://postgis.net/), it's meant specifically for these cases :)

Comment: That is what I am currently looking into, the documentation isn't too clear if I can continue using the `point` and `circle` I have or need to convert them somehow.

Comment: Seems like i have to use the `geometry` type, I'll continue reading about this. Thanks.